# How dotnet build chooses the output name

Tags: .net-core

First, let me explain the problem that causes this question.

If I create a new project using `dotnet new` and specifying a random project name with `-n` arg, then after doing `dotnet restore` - `dotnet build` from default bash terminal -> the final output name is **always** `React` + .output_type. Like:

```
/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/React.dll
```

I don't specify any additional arguments with `dotnet` commands. And looks like it doesn't matter what type of project to select: I have tried with `console` and `webapi`.

---

But I have found that if I open the project in VS Code and do the same `dotnet build` command from VS Code terminal (that is also bash) -> the output name is correct and equal to the `project_name+.output_type`.

So before I thought that output name is always taken from `.csproj` file name during building. But now it looks like something could override this behavior: different terminals - different env settings, etc.

Cause output name contains `React` I am blaming the react cli tooling, but this doesn't help me with identifying the reason of name-override.

I did `dotnet --info` from both terminals and output was the same:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.13
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.12-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/
```

Comment: msbuild also considers environment variables as "global properties" that can potentially override values in the project. Does `env` show any variables set to `React`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinUllrich, I have found that `$TARGETNAME` variable overrides the project name. Removing variable fix the problem:

```
> unset TARGETNAME
```