# Why is React.dll being included with new console projects in .Net Core 2?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core-2.0

Can't get the simplest .Net Core 2.0 console app to run on my macOS High Sierra.

As per the [Get started](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos) instructions, I created and tried to run the simplest app from Terminal:

```
dotnet new console -o myApp
cd myApp
dotnet run
```

The result is the error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in '/Users/xyz/Projects/myApp/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/'
```

Surprisingly, the /bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0 folder contains the files **React.dll** and **React.pdb**

The applications runs properly from within VS Code and VS 2017, but not from terminal.

Any idea why those React files are there and why the app doesn't run from Terminal?

### Info

myApp.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

myApp.runtimeconfig.json

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what happened but the problem seems to have disappeared after a reboot.

I strongly suspect that the problem was related to the global environmental variable (TARGETNAME), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572210/how-dotnet-build-chooses-the-output-name). In fact React.dll was the actual output of the build process and not just an unwanted dependency.

I am still puzzled as to why rebooting fixed the issue, since I had already tried closing and reopening terminal several times with no success.